# Angular StaticInjector error in production only

Tags: angular, ngx-spinner

When I try and run the prod build I get this error `ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(l)[u -> t]`:. When I try `ng serve --prod --optimization=false` the error becomes `ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgxSpinnerComponent -> NgxSpinnerService]`. I have however added NgXSpinnerModule to imports in my app.module.ts and am not sure what to do at this point. If I use `ng serve` like normal everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever version of ngx spinner you use needs to match your version of angular.

Answer (score 0):

import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";

constructor(
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService
  )

Add these in your component and then use spinner in your component